# CodeIgniter - Image upload

Tags: php

Whenever I choice file from browse and click upload, it does not work.

It is codeignitor project. I am new in php and codeignitor.

```
#My coctroller name is member and code is below:
public function profile_change_avater(){

    $this->load->model('member_model');

    if($this->input->post('upload'))
    {
        $this->member_model->do_upload();
    }
    $data['title'] = "Choise your Avater";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data['title']);
    echo "</pre>";
$this->common_load_view('member/user_extended_profile_change_avater_content_view',
'members', 'profile_change_avater', $data );

}

My model name is member_model, code is below:

public function do_upload(){

    //$this->image_path = realpath(APPPATH .'../asset/images' );
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $config = array(
        'allowed_type' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
        'upload_path'  => 'image_path',     
        'max_size'     => '2000'
    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();

    if( ! $this->upload->do_upload()){
        $error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_error());
        return $error;
    }
    else 
    {
        $data = array('upload_data'=> $this->upload->data());
        return $data;
    }


}
 Here is the code view:
<p id="avatar-upload">
<?php   echo  form_open_multipart('member/profile_change_avater');
    echo form_upload('userfile');
    echo form_submit('upload','Upload');
     echo form_close();
     ?>
</p>
```

What's wrong in my code. If any body help me. It world be great.

Comment: try http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html also 'upload_path'  => 'image_path/',

Answer (score 1):

in view

```
<p id="avatar-upload">
<?php   echo  form_open_multipart('member/profile_change_avater'); ?>
<input type="file" name='image'>
<?php    echo form_submit('upload','Upload');
     echo form_close();
     ?>
</p>
```

and change if condition of profile_change_avater()

```
if($this->input->post())
    {
        $config = array(

            'allowed_type' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
            'upload_path'  => 'image_path',     
            'max_size'     => '2000'
        );

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);


        if( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image')){
            $error = array('error'=>$this->upload->display_error());

        }
        else 
        {
            $data = array('upload_data'=> $this->upload->data());

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Controller

```
public function uesr_profile(){     
    if($this->input->post()){
        $config['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
        $config['upload_path'] = './';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp';
        $config['max_size'] = 1024 * 5;
        $config['max_width']  = 1024;
        $config['max_height']  = 768;   
        $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()){
            $this->data['error'] =  $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
    }      
        $this->load->view('profile_page',$this->data);              
}
```

## View

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('users/uesr_profile'); ?>
<input type="file" name='userfile'>
<?php  echo form_submit('upload','Upload');
echo form_close(); ?>
```